# Is unique MAX-2SAT NP-Complete?

Tags: complexity-theory

MAX-2SAT is NP-Complete.
If the solution is stipulated to be unique, is MAX-2SAT still NP-complete?

Comment: You might be able to use the same proof technique used to show that Unambiguous-SAT is NP-complete (Valiant & Vazirani).  I suggest you look up that reduction -- it's standard and well-known -- and see if you're able to apply it here.

Comment: What do you mean by "If the solution is stipulated to be unique?" Are you talking about a promise problem where you only have to deal with instances where there's only one assignment that satisfies the maximum possible number of clauses? The decision problem where you accept only if there's exactly one assignment that satisfies at least $k$ clauses? Something else?

Comment: David, Yes I should have used the more standard term, i.e., the solution is promised to be unique.  What prompted my question is that I have experimented with an algorithm for MAX-2SAT that seems to work extremely well when the maximizing assignment is unique - so I begin to wonder if unique MAX-2SAT is easier than the general problem.